# How to get a white outline around an image in CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to style an image with a white border around it like in the following:

[image]

If I did:

```
 <ul class="learn">
    <li class="thumbnaile" > <img id="portrait" src="/assets/allyson.jpg" class="stretch" />
    </li>
 </ul>
```

...then add padding to .thumbnaile...

Is there a better/ more efficient way of doing it than this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could either use `border` (which is certainly the obvious choice), but there's also `padding` and `box-shadow`:

```
img {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/McnEe/).

In this example the `img` element is padded by `4px`, which allows the `background-color` to extend out from 'behind' the image.

```
img {
    margin: 4px 0 0 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #fff;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/McnEe/1/).

Because `box-shadow` doesn't displace the element the `margin` is required to allow for the `box-shadow` to show on all sides.

Answer (score 7):

Just using the [border](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border) property should do what you want:

```
border: solid white 4px;
```

So long as the only part needing the border is the outer edge (of the rectangular image), that will surround it about as shown. You may want to modify the [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Box-sizing), if the border should cut into the image; but for padding, the defaults will work.

The border will work on the `<li>` or `<img>` tags, depending on how you want to lay the image(s) out (`<li>` will allow multiple images with no border *between* them).

Adding `padding` to the class will have a similar effect, but behave differently with regard to the box used for sizing and positioning the element. Padding on the `<li>` will have a very close effect to a proper border on the `<img>`, but placing the border on the `<img>` itself may simplify your CSS.