# Add image from user computer to canvas with style

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, fabricjs

I'm playing a lot with fabric.js. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226332/add-image-from-user-computer-to-canvas) how to add my own images. How would I do this but give each uploaded photo a certain style? In other words, I'd like each picture uploaded to have a border or stroke to look like this:

[image: like the photos have here].

The code I'm playing with:

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(f) {
    var data = f.target.result;
    fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function(img) {
      var oImg = img.set({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        angle: 00,
        width: 100,
        height: 100
      }).scale(0.9);
      canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
      var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
        format: 'png',
        quality: 0.8
      });
    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file"><br />
<canvas id="canvas" width="450" height="450"></canvas>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974494/how-to-get-a-white-outline-around-an-image-in-css .. You Want Like This .... ?

Comment: Yes, very much like that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to set `stroke` and `strokeWidth` property for the image object to accomplish that ...

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function (e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (f) {
        var data = f.target.result;
        fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
            var oImg = img.set({
                left: 40,
                top: 40,
                angle: 00,
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                stroke: '#07C', //<-- set this
                strokeWidth: 5  //<-- set this
            }).scale(0.9);
            canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
            var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
                format: 'png',
                quality: 0.8
            });
        });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

```css
canvas {border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file"><br />
<canvas id="canvas" width="180" height="180"></canvas>
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you!