# Add box-shadow to image styling on load with fabric.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, fabricjs

[Thanks to @ℊααnd I was able to add stroke styling to images added to the canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43921249/add-image-from-user-computer-to-canvas-with-style). I'd like to also have a drop shadow on any images added to give them more of a "stacked" look. I've tried adding boxShadow: "5px 5px 20px 0px #888888", and [taking queues from the documentation](http://fabricjs.com/shadows) but I'm not having any luck. How would I achieve this? Styling in JS is still totally new to me. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function (e) {
var file = e.target.files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (f) {
    var data = f.target.result;
    fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
        var oImg = img.set({
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            angle: 0,
            border: '#000',
            stroke: '#F0F0F0',
            strokeWidth: 40
        }).scale(0.2);
        canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
        //var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
            format: 'png',
            quality: 1
        });
    });
};
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

I tried plugging all of my code into the snippet inserter but for some reason it didn't want to run there. I figure the above is what's applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply create a shadow object, like this ...

```
var shadow = {
    color: '#888888',
    blur: 70,
    offsetX: 45,
    offsetY: 45,
    opacity: 0.8
}
```

and then, set it for the image object, like so ...

```
oImg.setShadow(shadow);
```

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ**

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function (e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (f) {
        var data = f.target.result;
        fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
           
           //create shadow
            var shadow = {
                color: '#888888',
                blur: 70,
                offsetX: 45,
                offsetY: 45,
                opacity: 0.8
            }
           
           var oImg = img.set({
                left: 0,
                top: 0,
                angle: 0,
                stroke: '#222',
                strokeWidth: 40
            }).scale(0.2);
            oImg.setShadow(shadow); //set shadow
            canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
                format: 'png',
                quality: 1
            });
        });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

```css
canvas {border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file"><br />
<canvas id="canvas" width="180" height="180"></canvas>
```